# AngularJS track by breaking binding with ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS in a project and have read that there could by some performance optimizing by using track by on `ng-options`.

Before the code worked fine, and looked like this:

```
<select ng-disabled="ctrl.FilteredProjects.length < 2" 
        class="filterDropDown col-sm-12" 
        ng-change="ctrl.UpdateFilteredTasks(); ctrl.GetProjectSummary(ctrl.filter.ProjectId);" 
        ng-model="ctrl.filter.ProjectId" 
        ng-options="x.Id as x.ProjectName for x in ctrl.FilteredProjects | orderBy : 'ProjectName'">
  <option value="">-All-</option>
</select>
```

The `ng-options` synced nicely with the ng-model, but after I added:                               `ng-options="x.Id as x.ProjectName for x in ctrl.FilteredProjects | orderBy : 'ProjectName' track by x.Id">`
the linking between the ng-model and the `ng-options` broke.

I get no JavaScript errors and then when I update the `ng-options` the model gets updated too. So the problem is just when I load the page and would like to set the value in the `ng-option` using the model.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add a fiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Have you tried : ng-options="x.Id as x.ProjectName for x in ctrl.FilteredProjects track by x.Id | orderBy : 'ProjectName'">

Comment: It's working without any issue. check this, https://jsfiddle.net/agh71b4s/